# getting Resource of a dependency Module

Tags: android

I want to theme an app with a separate module that i have built myself. The idea is to move most resource files like colors, drawables styles, to this new module and adding it as a dependency to the major app. What this would help me achieve is being able to change the resources from this module ( one of the requirement of the client). The  main app module depends on other modules like the pagersliding module which has been tweak a little. So, what i did was to make my theming module a dependency to pagersliding module while pagersliding module is now a dependency to my module. Major reason for this is making update to app ui without having to touch individual res folder of multiple dependency

The problem is that when i try referencing the style, i get resource not found error.

**Illustration:**

```
ImageButton mImage = (ImageButton) view;
mImage.getDrawable().mutate().setColorFilter(ColorFilterUtils.getFilteredColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.nav_item_color_default)));
```

`R.color.nav_item_color_default` is in the theming module

my guess is that it is getting the resource of the pagersliding module and it can not find R.color.nav_item_color_default in that resou

```
mImage.getDrawable().mutate().setColorFilter(ColorFilterUtils.getFilteredColor(getResources().getColor(com.packagename.theming.R.color.nav_item_color_default)));
```

on trying to run this, i encounter `package com.pakagename.theming.R` is not found error.

Do not really know if this can be done or if i am doing it the right way. But, is there anyway i can make reference to resource of a dependency module from another module without encoutering the `resource not found` error. Thanks